# Can use smart contract as payment gateway

Tags: contract-design, tokens, erc-20

Most suggest that cannot use ERC20 token as payment gateway integration .Why?

Comment: Can you clarify who is giving that suggestion? and what is their reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possibly confusion about the definition of terms?

If a "gateway" is meant to mean machinery and a "token" is meant to mean something like a currency, then the proposition doesn't make any sense for the same reason that a "dollar" can't be a "cash register".

It's perfectly fine to make a token the accepted "form" of payment. You need a point of sale or "gateway" system of some kind to process payments. The tokens don't pay themselves.

Hope it helps.